# How to call methods from a Thymeleaf template in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a method in class CommonUtils which I am trying to call in Thymeleaf, but it throws error

> EL1004E: Method call: Method ConvertSecToHHMM(java.lang.Integer)
> cannot be found on type com.exm.util.CommonUtils

```
@Component
public class CommonUtils {

    // function convert second into hours and minutes.
    public  String ConvertSecToHHMM(int n) {
        n = n % (24 * 3600);
        int hour = n / 3600;

        n %= 3600;
        int minutes = n / 60 ;

        String finalTime = hour + " " + "hr " + minutes + " " + "min ";
        return finalTime;
    }
}
```

In Thymeleaf I wrote this

```
<td th:text="${T(com.exm.util.CommonUtils).ConvertSecToHHMM(recentActivities.timeSpent)}"></td>
```

when I make the method ConvertSecToHHMM(int n) static it works fine. **But I don't want to make that method static**.

So I tried another approach using bean injection; it also doesn't work for me:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurations {
    @Bean
    public static String ConvertSecToHHMM(int n) {
        n = n % (24 * 3600);
        int hour = n / 3600;

        n %= 3600;
        int minutes = n / 60 ;

        String finalTime = hour + " " + "hr " + minutes + " " + "min ";
        return finalTime;
    }

}
```

I get this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method ConvertSecToHHMM in com.exm.configurations.MyConfigurations required a bean of type 'int' that could not be found.
```

Is there any way I can create my util methods in a separate class and I can call them from Thymeleaf whenever I want?

Comment: *Just* for starters, if your method is a pure function, *why* don't you want it to be static?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application startup is failing because of `@Bean` method, spring is unable to find the value `n` to create the bean. You need to remove the Bean method and call the CommonUtils method directly:

```
<p th:text="${@commonUtils.ConvertSecToHHMM(500)}"></p>
```